# require('mysql') fails using NodeJS server in OpenShift

Tags: mysql, node.js, openshift, require

I have seen many posts here in this regard and tried many options.
I have even tried running the install in `app-root/runtime/repo`.

The 'npm install mysql' works fine - screen output shows installed, but no files are created in the node_modules folder (as seen via 'ls' or 'dir'). Fail line in app.js: `var mysql = require("mysql");`.

`tail -f app-root/logs/nodejs.log` shows lots of these ....

```
Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:339:15)
```

I am using OpenShift 'NodeJs Latest' pre-configured application.
Cartridges MySQL and phpMyAdmin installed and working well ( it seems)

I have run out of ideas.  Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suspecting permissions or similar prevention by the OpenShift host process, I tried a local install to the git cloned repo.

In the same folder as the app, I issued `npm install --save mysql`
This installed mysql using the version of node installed locally.

I then checked the changes in via git, and voila - problem solved.

Hope this helps someone else some day :)

Comment: To mark this question as done, would you click the tick mark to the left of this answer post, so that the symbol turns green? Thanks.